# ValueError in ConfigParser in python3

Tags: python, configparser

I am trying to update my `configuration.ini` file's, `[Financial Times: Financial-Services]` section's  `last_entry_id` with the following string:
 `http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/46858280-36f4-11e6-a780-b48ed7b6126f.html?ftcamp=published_links%2Frss%2Fcompanies_financial-services%2Ffeed%2F%2Fproduct`
 
Here is my `configuration.ini` file's corresponding section:

```
[Financial Times: Financial-Services]
feed_updated_on = 
feed_updated_field = ['updated']
link = http://www.ft.com/rss/companies/financial-services
last_entry_id = 
id_field = link
```

But in my code, when I try the following line:

```
id_of_first_link = 'http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/46858280-36f4-11e6-a780-b48ed7b6126f.html?ftcamp=published_links%2Frss%2Fcompanies_financial-services%2Ffeed%2F%2Fproduct'
feed_link['last_entry_id'] = id_of_first_link
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: invalid interpolation syntax in 'http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/46858280-36f4-11e6-a780-b48ed7b6126f.html?ftcamp=published_links%2Frss%2Fcompanies_financial-services%2Ffeed%2F%2Fproduct' at position 90
```

`feed_link` is the reference name of `[Financial Times: Financial-Services]` in the `configuration.ini` file. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: This is going to sound random but can you try `id_of_first_link = id_of_first_link.replace('%', '%%')` before putting it into the dictionary, and see what happens?

Comment: It works! But there is no change in the string. Why is it so? Here is the new string after the replace function: `http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/46858280-36f4-11e6-a780-b48ed7b6126f.html?ftcamp=published_links%2Frss%2Fcompanies_financial-services%2Ffeed%2F%2Fproduct`

Comment: The percent signs have special meaning and putting them twice seems to allow to escape them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception refers to an invalid `interpolation syntax`

This is because in Python you're able to *interpolate* strings with the following syntax:

```
mystring = "Hello, my name is %s"
print(mystring % 'StackOverflow')
```

I think that at some point in `configparser`, it must be using this syntax, and therefore is getting a string that it cannot handle correctly.

There are a few ways to get around this. You can either use the `str.replace()` that I showed you, which escapes `%` by using a double percent sign `%%`...

Or you can try to provide a raw string instead, with this syntax:

```
id_of_first_link = r'http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/46858280-36f4-11e6-a780-b48ed7b6126f.html?ftcamp=published_links%2Frss%2Fcompanies_financial-services%2Ffeed%2F%2Fproduct'
```

Note the `r` before the starting single-quote.

Raw strings will also allow you to type strings like `r'C:\Windows\system32'` without the backslashes escaping characters accidently.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks.

Comment: I am getting a problem in converting the `id_of_first_link` to a raw string, since the program is directly storing the value `http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/46858280-36f4-11e6-a780-b48ed7b6126f.html?ftcamp=published_links%2Frss%2Fcompanies_financial-services%2Ffeed%2F%2Fproduct` in the `id_of_first_link`, I am unable to find a way to convert this to raw string. I tried `id_of_first_link.encode('string-escape')`, but it gives me error `LookupError: unknown encoding: string-escape`